# Music Theory behind build ups

Tags: sheet-music, beats

So a very common technique to use in an Electronic Dance Music (EDM) song is to create a build up by increasing the speed of the beat until it stops and drops (then proceeding to melt the face of the listener).

My question is, when the speed is increasing, is the BPM increasing in the music notation side or are more note being placed in the same BPM?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a couple of techniques here:

If you are gradually ramping up the speed, then you would use an increase in tempo. This gives a growing sense of urgency, but can be very difficult to manage, as when you drop the beat you need to ensure the new tempo matches, or is a fraction of that fast tempo. This is almost certainly not what you are describing.

Much more commonly in EDM, before a drop what you see is a doubling of notes in the bar, and then doubling again etc. This doesn't change the overall beat pace (BPM is a bit deceptive here) but does give you many more notes.

This looks a little like:

`X - - - X - - - X - - - X - - - X - X - X - X - X X X X X X X X drop!`

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! I'm not sure who to mark as correct between yourself and @topo - both seem valid and good! :)

Comment: @topo and I mention the tempo increase -this has been used throughout musical history. The beat doubling is very EDM specific in this form. Simple solution when accepting - don't rush...someone else may come with a better answer. And just accept the one that best helps you :-)

Comment: Wise words! :) will give it til tomorrow then will choose whichever one best suits my question :) thank you for your time :D

Comment: To add, the actual tempo of club tracks like this (almost?) never changes for a very good reason.  These types of tracks are all mixed as singles with long intros and outros where intruments are gradually brought in and let out to give the DJ both a metronome and some sound space to mix tracks together.  Usually you'll hear 12-36 bars of overlap where the beat from the outgoing track continues (with the highs and/or mids progressively cut back) with some elements from the incoming track playing overtop.  At some point the bass EQ gets flipped to the new track and things continue seamlessly.

Comment: In any case, the DJ is usually cueing up the next track in headphones while the first is playing and it's not uncommon to want to get the tempos of both tracks in sync before the build. This means the real tempo has to stay locked through the build so that the incoming track is still on beat when everything settles back in. Note doubling is an easy strategy to get the sense of urgency without actually messing the tempo. These types of tracks are woefully formulaic for a reason. It helps the DJ to mix without memorizing the patterns for every single song.  Intro, theme, build, drop, jam, outro.

Comment: There's another problem with changing the tempo, which is that it doesn't lend itself well to dancing. All the crazy changes need to happen over a consistent beat.

Comment: The other thing to consider with a tempo change is that there are some effects used that are based on the tempo, so a change in tempo would also affect how a DAW handles those effects.  For example, a delay effect is often made to sync with the beat (though it can be set independent of the beat), so if you were to change the tempo, it would change the frequency of the repeats.

Comment: I'd also note that a delay is sometimes the source of the increase in the amount of notes heard.  If you set your feedback to infinite, then automate the delay time to slowly decrease (shorter amount of time between repeats), then it will have the effect of the tempo increasing.  You would probably need to automate the feedback length and/or the automate it on/off.

Comment: Tempo changes are *virtually non-existent* in EDM. I think the latter is what the OP is looking for. It's practically a requirement for a punk rock song.

Comment: I'll tweak my post to make that more obvious

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard in EDM not only doubling, but use of triplets, e.g. quarter notes to eighth notes to eighth note triplets to sixteenth notes to sixteenth note sextuplets etc.

Answer (score -1):

For a buildup, you increase the BPM.  Actually, it typically leads to *fewer* notes being placed in the same amount of beats: but the various instruments tend to decrease their amount of notes (playing 3 instead of 4 on a beat, 2 instead of 3, 3 on 2 beats, as trioles or staggered and so on) at different points of time in the acceleration.  So there is an overall sense of gradual acceleration but the instruments tend to lower their individual workload at various points of time while driving it.

Similar to an "endlessly rising scale", just with rhythm instead of pitch.

Comment: -1 The overwhelming majority of EDM does not change tempo. As described in [Doctor Mayhem's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/63912/3265), the actual effect is an increase in the density of the rhythms being played.